# How to set onItemTouchlistener in recyclerview in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to perform some action in `onTouch` event of `recyclerview` item, in `kotlin`, but i am not able to do that. Please help.

In java we can call `recyclerview.onItemTouchListener` in activity, so that we can perform tasks inside activity itself.

Is there same option for kotlin?

Comment: Please share more information. It's difficult to identify your problem from your question.

Comment: I am new in kotlin.

Comment: can you plz share your code xml and item adapter

Answer (score 0):

A more complete example of the Adapter and the ViewHolder can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview?gclid=CjwKCAjwquWVBhBrEiwAt1KmwlgwGEI5C3q4zLkXd7_7RP7HRQGNGAUCXQ1Cc_9lnLKEQaHp-cX89hoC1AcQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

example code:

```
class MyAdapter : ListAdapter<ItemObject, MyAdapter.ViewHolder>(ItemObject.DIFF_COMPARATOR) {

    ....

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
       ....
       holder.bind()
    }

   inner class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
      fun bind(){
         ...
         itemView.setOnTouchListener { v, event -> YOUR CODE GOES HERE }
      }
   }
}
```